# How can I find out which tab is playing music?

Tags: google-chrome

Part of the research I do online, with Google Chrome, requires me to go to several sites including those who, for some dumb reason, think it's alright to hide the music player.

If I want to listen to music I can play my own and I usually am listening to something else when a random site starts playing random looped songs.

So, how can I find out which tab is playing music, and eventually mute it?

Comment: [How to geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/105496/how-to-find-which-tab-is-making-a-noise-in-google-chrome-and-mute-it/) explains the `MuteTab` usage may be it will helpful for you.

Comment: @avirk MuteTab has already been posted as an answer and it only worked for me in a few cases.

Comment: That's why I just posted the explanation of that. I'll check out if I find anything better.

Comment: In which cases it doesn't work for you? You can also try out the [music controller](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/epcaphpkbbgbdbfbalehicknhhnlpmca/reviews?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon) see if it help out.

Comment: Check out the [sound on click](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ejchjkneplcffgcopialnjofdhhggjik/details?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon) too.

Comment: Found [this one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/go-to-playing-tab/hmbhamadknmmkapmhbldodoajkcggcml). Adds a buton with a list of tabs making sounds

Answer (score 5):

[MuteTab Beta](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/djiagjcjenpnblipghgnefmcflecpbgf) solved the problem for me.

Although this is not the best solution, since this is a beta version, the fixes available in this version will eventually get in the stable version so MuteTab will work again.

Comment: I don't extensively tested this extension, so please tell me if you have any problems since I'm also interested in an extension that works globally.

Comment: I've tested a little bit more, and with this version you can even play/pause execution of audio in sites like Youtube, or others that as some kind of playable audio or video.

Comment: I like how you can use the panic button and shut down whatever is playing.

Answer (score 3):

[MuteTab](http://www.mutetab.com/) is an extension for Chrome that detects which tab is playing music and allows you to mute them.

[image]

Comment: That's interesting except it doesn't work. I ran a test and it gave me seven different "possible sources" of twelve. It's also been reported to consume a ridiculously high amount of RAM - http://goo.gl/adegh

Comment: This is the link for it at the Chrome Web Store:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nmkbaaijgpppbokgnhhoakihofedkgcc

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: *> That's interesting except it doesn't work. I ran a test and it gave me seven different "possible sources" of twelve.*    @Rennan, so what's wrong with that, it's barely more than half of all tabs. `:-D` But seriously, I think it is just detecting if there are Flash, HTML5, Silverlight, or Java elements in the page. I'd have to check the source to be sure, but if it does, then of course it is going to give lots of false-positives.

Answer (score 3):

In Chrome there's a small button icon to the right of your extensions. Click it and you'll see listed all the tabs that are currently playing audio followed by those that can but aren't. [image: The Button Icon]

Answer (score 1):

Use this Chrome extension:
[image][Go to Playing Tab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/go-to-playing-tab/hmbhamadknmmkapmhbldodoajkcggcml)

With this extension, you jump directly to the tabs that are currently playing sound.

Answer (score 0):

I normally have numerous windows and tabs open and looking for a tab by the sound icon is a time consuming case of 'where is waldo'.

It's not a perfect solution but using the built in 'Task Manager' and sorting by 'Idle wakeups' column helps me find the culprit much quicker.

[image: locating tab playing music]

Answer (score 0):

I use [Volume Booster](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/volume-booster/flfgnikpbnkalibambfjdnfdambpmfcj), which has the added benefit of boosting audio if needed.

Music playing tabs appear in the popup window of the extension, focus on click, and there you can pause or mute the player or tab if the player lacks controls.

Comment: Go To Playing Tab also works https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/go-to-playing-tab/hmbhamadknmmkapmhbldodoajkcggcml/related

Comment: Chrome now has a built-in feature that appears when tabs make sound.