# How can I find out which browser tab last played a notification sound?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

I usually have a lot of tabs open in both Chrome and Firefox. Occasionally, I'll hear what sounds like some kind of notification. Long sounds/music can be tracked easily using the speaker icon on the tab (c.f. [How can I find out which tab is playing music?](https://superuser.com/questions/414504/how-can-i-find-out-which-tab-is-playing-music)), but quick sounds don't give me a chance. Is it Discord? Email? Some other chat? I can click through the tabs I expect notifications from, but sometimes it's none of those.

Is there a way to find out, not which tab is *currently* playing sounds, but which tab *last played* a sound?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to find out, not which tab is currently playing sounds, but which tab last played a sound?

I believe the short answer to this is "only with a browser extension".

That is, as I understand it, the current crop of mainstream browsers (including Chrome and Firefox) don't generate any messages regarding sound events outside themselves. So an extension would likely be needed to internally track each tab that played a sound, the time the event occurred and then export that data to the user (say, via a special browser-only web page or exporting text logs somehow).

There are event logging/monitoring extensions available, but none that I am aware of for this particular purpose (though I think it might be somewhat popular if there was one... this isn't the first time this question has come up).